# Programmatically change product attribute at store view level

Tags: magento

I'm sorry if this question is trivial but I've been struggling to find what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to change the value of an attribute on a store view level but the default is also changed whereas it shouldn't be. Of course, this attribute is set up to be "store-view-scoped". To keep it simple, I've tried with the product name. No success.

Below are unsuccessful tests I've tried...

Do you see what I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks.

---

My tries :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);
$product->setStoreId(STORE_ID)->setName('new_name')->save();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);
$product->setStoreId(STORE_ID)->setStore(STORE_CODE)->setName('new_name')->save();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);
$product->setStoreId(STORE_CODE)->setName('new_name')->save();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(STORE_ID)->load(PRODUCT_ID);
$product->setName('new_name')->save();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(STORE_ID)->load(PRODUCT_ID);
$product->setStoreId(STORE_ID)->setName('new_name')->save();
```

I even tried by adding the line below before the product model load...

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(STORE_ID);
```

Comment: Does it work if you add ->setWebsiteId($websiteId) on there too?

Comment: Nope... Doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How can i remove all products from a selected website in multistore?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

So here is the complete snippet to change attribute value for a specific product attribute on a specific store view. Example with the product name :

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);
$product->setStoreId(STORE_ID)->setName('my_new_product_name')->save();
```

And as an additional answer, one could be interested in changing the attribute value to the default one. In this case, the argument 'false' must be passed to the setAttribute :

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);
$product->setStoreId(STORE_ID)->setName(false)->save();
```

Comment: Hey @ʍǝɥʇɐɯ, I am updating product price at per store view level and ended with no success. Is this answer work for price too

Comment: please tell me the path too magentio2.2.4

Comment: if anyone looking for how to implement this in Magento 2 here is the link **https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173763/73212**

Answer (score 12):

You need to set the current store to admin at the top of your code block:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Comment: Please see below my own answer for the complete snippet + interesting additional information. Thanks ʍǝɥʇɐɯ for your help.

Answer (score 3):

note when loading product with data for some store view, also default values get loaded. saving such product will save default values as store values (thus unset "Use Default Value" for fields)
i ended up with following function to clean-up product data from default values

```
public static function _removeDefaults($item) {
    static $attributeCodes = null;
    if($attributeCodes == null) {
        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)->getAttributeCollection();
        $attributeCodes = array();
        foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
            $ac = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            if(in_array($ac, array('sku','has_options','required_options','created_at','updated_at','category_ids'))) {
                continue;
            }
            $attributeCodes[] = $ac;
        }
    }
    foreach($attributeCodes as $ac) {
        if(false == $item->getExistsStoreValueFlag($ac)) {
            $item->unsetData($ac);
        }
    }
}
```

remember to send only product loaded for some store view